# Laravel Авторизация

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть проект на laravel с админкой в orchid, я переделал авторизацию, но столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно что бы при авторизации я получал конкретные ошибки, но как это сделать??
Код выглядит так:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);

    $auth = $this->guard->attempt([
        'email' => $credentials['email'],
        'password' => $credentials['password'],
        'status' => User::$status['active']
    ], $request->filled('remember'));

    if ($auth) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => __('The details you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.'),
        'password' => __('auth.password'),
        'status' => __('auth.status')
    ]);
}
```

Сейчас если есть какая-то ошибка, то я получаю все 3 ошибки. Как мне узнать в чем конкретно ошибка, через метод attemp? Или мне как-то по другому надо авторизировать ??

Comment: Хорошо бы приложить путь к файлу. Так ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем решил сделать так:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('The details you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.'),
        ]);
    }

    if ($user->status !== User::$status['active']) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'status' => __('auth.status')
        ]);
    }

    Auth::login($user, $request->filled('remember'));

    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Вроде работает